# sqlite - How do I select distinct row by date?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a schema as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE fruit ( name TEXT, date_collected TEXT);
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO fruit (name, date_collected) VALUES ('red apples', '2020-02-04 08:04:37+00:00');
INSERT INTO fruit (name, date_collected) VALUES ('red apples', '2020-06-01 04:36:09+00:00');
INSERT INTO fruit (name, date_collected) VALUES ('mangoes', '2020-03-18 19:14:24+00:00');
INSERT INTO fruit (name, date_collected) VALUES ('mangoes', '2017-04-20 19:14:24+00:00');
INSERT INTO fruit (name, date_collected) VALUES ('watermelon', '2019-12-20 14:29:02+00:00');
```

How do I select output that shows only the newest distinct fruit entries by date?

e.g.

```
red apples | 2020-06-01 04:36:09+00:00
mangoes | 2020-03-18 19:14:24+00:00
watermelon | 2019-12-20 14:29:02+00:00
```

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use MAX for the timestamp.

Comment: thanks @jarlh You commented first, but Gordon was the first to answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the maximum date, then use aggregation:

```
select name, max(date_collected)
from fruit
group by name;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
select
    Name
    ,max(convert(date,date_collected)) [MostRecentDate]

from
    fruit

group by
    Name

order by
    [MostRecentDate] desc
```

Comment: Your answer is more detailed, but Gordon answered first. Cheers.